# Device identification without device ID and on Nougat

Tags: java, android

I am interested to how I can identify user with some alternative way:

- I don't want to use device ID because it demands permission and ask user, it ruins my app
- I cannot use MAC address because from Nugat its not allowed
- Other authentication things are not unique

I need some unique device identifier what I can use without permissions to assign user in database to his device.

Comment: Generate a UUID on the device, and store it in internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`), to uniquely identify a particular app installation.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method is to generate a unique ID for your app and store it in the app's local data. That allows your app to remember if it's the same device while it's installed, but not across installs.

e.g.,

```
SharedPrefs prefs = ...;
String id = prefs.getString("my.id");
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
  prefs.edit.putString("my.id", UUID.randomUUID()).apply();
}
```

Note that the inability to obtain a persistent device identifier is by design. You shouldn't be tracking users like that. If the user uninstalls your app, you should "forget" about them completely.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [InstanceID](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID) is for, it generates a unique ID that you can then use to associate data with. The reason this is a better approach than a UUID is that anytime you need to get the token you will most of the time get the same one and if it changes you will be notified which at that time you would update your backend with the new ID.

A UUID will always give you something new

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/

Comment: Or see my post if you don't want to include megabytes of Google libs and wonder why Google created a helper class for such a simple concept.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman InstanceID is far more than just a helper and is far more beneficial to use than a UUID. You cannot query a UUID and get information about if the user is active or even if the key is still valid

Comment: How would the key be invalid? All of the cases listed in the docs for `InstanceID` are handled in the solution I posted.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman key will be invalid when the user uninstalls the app leaving orphaned data on the server.

Comment: So, same as the solution I posted?

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman what is the same? UUID will create orphaned data InstanceID will not since you can query a key

Comment: @tyczj so If I use InstanceID, the ID will be always the same? What if user uninstall the app and install again?

Comment: @ŁukaszMaćczak No the ID can change but you get notified when it changes which is when you would update your server with the new ID. `Tokens are unique and secure, but your app or the Instance ID service may need to refresh tokens in the event of a security issue or when a user uninstalls and reinstalls your app during device restoration. Your app must implement a listener to respond to token refresh requests from the Instance ID service.`

Answer (score 0):

Device ID and MAC address are unique ids used everywhere. But naugat will not allow access to MAC address.

You can use registeration ID of the mobile. It is the unique id google server generates for us. This ID is used to imolement GCM based notifications. I have implemented GCM based notifications thats why it came as an idea to use this id as unique id.

You can search for GCM based push notifications in android. You will find how to generate this Reg. Id. It'll require gcm library and internet permissions.

**To capture uninstalls**
Reg Ids are very long 4096 bytes so not preferred to be sotred in db as unique id. Solutioon can be,
When you get NotRegistered error or the app is uninstalled, you should indeed delete that registration ID from your DB (or at least mark it with a status that says it is inactive, and stop sending messages to it). But if the app will be re-installed on a device from which it was earlier uninstalled, the app may get the same registration ID when it registers again to GCM, so your server should allow registration IDs that at one point gave NotRegistered to become active again.

You should update the old registration ID when you get canonical registration ID in the response from Google.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this doesn't require any permission

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String androidId = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```